# Navbar inside flex item oveflow issue

Tags: tailwind-css

I am using tailwind css vanilla and I want to create a navbar inside the flex item that I have assigned as the visual page header content placeholder.

I encounter a problem while working on this, I have added padding all around with p-8 to the navbar element and I have notice that the navbar is overflowing over the flex item that is holding it.

I do not understand why is this behavior happening because I have added overflow-hidden to the flex item that is holding the navbar. Padding is not considered to be content?

I have tried different combination with display property and also with positioning, all without any result, therefore I need some help.

This is what I have done so far.

```html
<link href="https://unpkg.com/tailwindcss@2.0.3/dist/tailwind.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="container mx-auto px-4 h-screen">
    <div class="flex flex-col h-full content-start">
        <div class="flex-grow w-full overflow-hidden bg-gradient-to-r from-purple-400 via-pink-500 to-red-500">
            <nav class="p-8">
                    <a class="" href="#">
                        Home
                    </a>
                    <a class="" href="#">
                        Products
                    </a>
                    <a class="" href="#">
                        Discounts
                    </a>
                    <a class="" href="#">
                        Customers
                    </a>
            </nav>
        </div>

        <div class="flex-grow my-px px-px w-full overflow-hidden bg-gradient-to-r from-purple-400 via-pink-500 to-red-500 h-full">
            <!-- Column Content -->
            2
        </div>

        <div class="flex-grow my-px px-px w-full overflow-hidden bg-gradient-to-r from-purple-400 via-pink-500 to-red-500 h-5">
            <!-- Column Content -->
            3
        </div>

    </div>
</div>
```

Thank you!

L.E. If you shrink the browser, the when the flex column item shrinks it overlaps the previous item. I have shrieked the browser window and I have notice that element 1 of the flex box is going under element 2 and if I go further I'm left only with element 3, the other 2 are going behind the last element 3 of the flex-box.

Comment: what is the problem? I can't understand. Set a background to nav and see that there is no  any overflowing.

Comment: Why down vote if you didn't bother seeing what is the problem? Have you looked at the navbar elements how are padded over the next element of the flex item (2) how I have described in my question? The pading value on the bottom of the nav elements is gone.

Comment: You don't need the overflow-hidden class. Your nav wrapper getting sized depends on the size of the nav. Just remove this and everything is fine